# Workflow orchestration tool compatible with Windows Server 2013?

Tags: job-scheduling, airflow, orchestration, luigi, data-pipeline

My current project requires automation and scheduled execution of a number of tasks (copy a file, send an email when a new file arrives in a directory, execute an analytics job, etc). My plan is to write a number of individual shell scripts for each task but would need a workflow orchestration/job flow management tool.

I am aware of a number of workflow orchestration tools such as Airflow, Luigi, Azkaban and have used them in the past as well, but those seem to be designed for *nix systems and unless i am mistaken they don't support Windows.

What are some good tools and solutions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant guide for a Data Engineer https://github.com/pawl/awesome-etl

EDIT
Apparently since adding gunicorn, airflow has not been compatible with windows.

Comment: I am aware of Airflow and it definitely fits the bill and is great. It was actually my first preference as well, but after spending a lot of time trying to make it work on Windows 8, i have given up. Have you had success making it run on Windows?

Comment: You're right about airflow on windows. Updated the answer to just include that list of alternatives.